# Camera rotation issues in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, rotation

I am unable to rotate the camera in my Three.js scene within a certain degree.

The goal is that the camera tweens along a path constructed using positions and rotations of meshes. Tweening along positions works perfectly fine but rotations only work so-and-so. The camera rotations work fine up until a certain range of degrees, around 90 - 270. I'm only rotating the camera around its y-axis so I don't think gimbal-lock is causing the issue here unless I'm understanding gimbal-lock wrong.

See the desired path here: 
[image: Example Camera Path]
This shows that the camera starts at mesh 1, and tweens its location along each of the meshes. It attempts to rotate to the rotation of the meshes too, which works fine up until the third or fourth node, where the rotation seems to break and appear mirrored or offset.

See another example here, showing the camera directions visualized:
[image: Camera Direction visualized along another path]
The red lines indicated the direction of the cameras frustum, and the cones indicate the direction it should be facing in. The values at the top are the rotation values of the meshes along their y-axis. You can see that at rotations 135 and 260, the red lines do not match the direction of the cones.

There isn't so much to the code - it's using tween.js to simply rotate the cameras y-value using an array as values to interpolate along. I've tried not using interpolation and just tweening to the mismatched rotations directly and this appears wrong, too.

```
let r = new TWEEN.Tween(common.camera.rotation, this.tweens)
    .to({
        y: path.rotations.y
    }, 5000)
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None);
```

Where `path.rotations.y` is an array of Y values `[0.0174, 0.436, -1.047, -1.570, -0.806]` (these values correspond to the rotations of the first image, not the second).

It should also be noted that rotations from Blender don't seem to match the rotations in Threejs. E.g. Cone 6's rotation is 226 degrees, which is 3.94444 radians. But the rotation in Threejs is listed as -0.806 radians. However, visually they appear right in the scene. I'm exporting the scenes using Blender and a GLTF Exporter plugin.

The expected result is that the cameras rotation matches the rotation of the cones, but actually they just match when they are in a certain degree.

Live example: 
http://davidpuetter.com/games/threejs-test/
Click on the game to start the tween. Once it's done, press Q to view it from overhead. You can see in the top right one, the lines didn't match.

Code available here:
https://github.com/davidpox/threejs-test
Sorry for very messy code, this was stripped out of a project thats under NDA.

Comment: Would be great to provide an editable working example.

Comment: @prisoner849 Sorry for the delay! I added a live example and the code via a Github Repo :) Thank you!